# Using content_for inside a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

This is a weird requirement that may need another approach, but my brain is stuck.

I want to accomplish something like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter Proc.new { share_params :user_name }, :only => :show
  render_djs
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include ActionView::Helpers::CaptureHelper
  def share_params(*shared)
    content_for(:djs) { shared.inspect }
  end

  def self.render_djs
    before_filter Proc.new {
      render :inline => "<%= yield(:djs) %>" if request.format.djs?
    }
  end
end
```

I want to use `content_for` because I may want to add content to the `:djs` yield in other filters.

However, this code raises `undefined method output_buffer=`.

I suppose I could use an instance variable, but this seems cleaner, doesn't it?

Comment: For future readers, refer to @Camden's answer using a instance variable passed to the view. Controllers are not supposed to know what you want to do with your information, but just to pass it to the view (and `content_for()` is a view thing). It's not called "Model-View-Controller" for nothing.

Answer (score 14):

You need to use the [`#view_context`](http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Rendering/view_context) method to reach the view context and then you can do the same as you would do in a view:

```
view_context.content_for(:something, view_context.render(partial: 'some_partial'))
```

Comment: ...neither in Rails 5 apparently.

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris Cristian Hey guys, see my answer above.

Answer (score 6):

you can't use `content_for` in controllers, even you knew `view_context` can provide the method.
see the issue here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4906

the method `view_context` always returns a new object. when you call `view_context.content_for(:somethin, 'content')` it will store content in instance variable of the new object.

you can do an experiment in controllers like the following:

```
view_context.content_for(:title, 'hello')
view_context.view_flow.content # => {}

a = view_context
a.content_for(:title, 'hello')
a.view_flow.content # =>  {:title=>"hello"}
```

anyway, if you still want to use `content_for` in controllers, you can override `view_context` in controllers as a workaround. but I don't know whether any side effects.

```
def view_context
  @_view_context ||= super
end
```

Comment: The workaround seems fine so far in Rails 7.0.3. I'm gonna go with it and will update if I discover a hidden gotcha (for example with turbo...)

Answer (score 4):

I found this helpful very much in case of setting title for my page.

I can just set content_for from controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    content_for :title, "List of posts"
    ...
  end
end
```

https://gist.github.com/hiroshi/985457
https://github.com/clmntlxndr/content_for_in_controllers

Comment: Trying this at the moment and on Rails 3.2 at least, it doesn't work. content_for(:title) from the view does, but from the controller, it seems to go into a black hole.

Comment: did you try adding this gem ? https://github.com/clmntlxndr/content_for_in_controllers

Comment: I didn't add the gem itself but I did take its code to see if it worked. It looks like Rails has started erasing the view context between the controller being called and the template being rendered, so the context array you set from the controller doesn't get used from the view. I ended up using something much simpler anyway, setting @title from the controller and then having the view do the content_for.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this! I was able to use this solution to override my page titles. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

If like me you are just looking to set content in the controller like a title, then it's probably better to just use a variable that's automatically passed to views and helpers. eg.

controller:

```
class AController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_title
  private
    def set_title
      @title = 'Email Subscription'
    end
end
```

and the helper:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def title_suffix
    " - #{@title}" unless @title.nil?
  end
end
```

and the template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Standard Title<%= title_suffix %></title>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a cleaner way than setting content_for from the controller.

In my case I have sidebar which needs to be displayed for every view.

In my layout I have

```
<%= yield :sidebar %>
```

Then I have a partial called `_set_sidebar.html.erb` which does this

```
<% content for :sidebar do %>
   <% render :partial => "layouts/sidebar", locals => {:locs => locs} %>
<% end %>
```

Then I just put a one liner in every view that I want to also have that sidebar

```
<%= render :partial => "layouts/set_sidebar", locals => {:locs => locs}
```

Otherwise I was previously using this

https://gist.github.com/985457 with .html_safe when I used render_to_string

Comment: "Then I just put a one liner in *every* view that I want to also have that sidebar" This is what [layouts](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts) are for (for future readers).

Answer (score 0):

`view_context` did not work in 5.1.4

`render inline: erb` however, did:

```ruby
    render inline: <<~ERB, layout: 'layout_expecting_subtabs'
      <% content_for(:subtabs, render(partial: 'somewhere/subtabs') )  %>
      <h1> yielded content </h1>
    ERB
```